# Let $V$ be vector space over $K$, $v_1,...v_n$ linearly independent and $v_{n+1}\in V$\Span{$v_1,...v_n$} Show $v_1,...v_n,v_{n+1}$ are linearly indep

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and $v_1, ... v_n$ linearly independent, and $v_{n+1} \in V$ \ Span{$v_1, ... v_n$}. Show that $v_1, ... v_n, v_{n+1}$ are linearly independent.

---

Any idea how to prove that ?

My idea is that if $v_{n+1} \notin$ Span{$v_1, ... v_n$}, then it cannot be expressed as linear combination of those vectors.
Also $v_1, ... v_n$ linearly independent means
$$a_1v_1 + .... a_nv_n = 0 \implies a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$$

But if we write
$$ a_1v_1 + .... a_nv_n + a_{n+1}v_{n+1} = 0$$ then we have
$$ a_1v_1 + .... a_nv_n = - a_{n+1}v_{n+1} $$

Which isn't necessarily zero, isn't it ? Or is what I did until now wrong ?

Comment: You had the right starting point. You just need to discuss the two cases $a_{n+1}=0$ and $a_{n+1}\neq 0$. If $a_{n+1}=0$ then all other must be zero. If $a_{n+1} \neq 0$ then $v_{n+1}$ is in the subspace generated by the other $v_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $v_1,...,v_{n+1}$ are linearly dependent. Then there exist $a_i$, not all zero such that
$$a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n+a_{n+1}v_{n+1} = 0.$$

If $a_{n+1}=0$ then the linear independence of $v_1,...,v_n$ implies that $a_i=0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, which contradicts our choice of $a_i$ (not all zero).

If $a_{n+1} \neq 0$ then
$$ v_{n+1} = -\frac{a_1}{a_{n+1}}v_1-...-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}v_n$$
showing that $v_{n+1}$ is in the subspace generated by $v_1,...v_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I did not think of doing that, but now it makes sense. Merci beaucoup !